# Pegar dados do banco com Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

A minha dúvida é como chamar algumas informações do DB para a página de impressão de um sistema em PHP, desenvolvido em *Codeigniter*.

No DB dos users "doctor", eu tenho as seguintes tabelas: 
`doctor_id`,`name`,`email`,`password`,`address`,`phone`,`department_id`,`profile`

O código abaixo, chama o nome do médico, além de outras informações de outra tabela, do paciente, para a página de impressão. Mas, eu gostaria de saber como incluir, na mesma linha do nome do médico, as informações de "profile" e "address"?

```
<?php 
$edit_data = $this->db->get_where('prescription', array('prescription_id' => $param2))->result_array(); 
foreach ($edit_data as $row): 
$patient_info = $this->db->get_where('patient' , array('patient_id' => $row['patient_id'] ))->result_array(); 
?> 
<div id="prescription_print"> 
<div><b><?php $name = $this->db->get_where('doctor' , array('doctor_id' => $row['doctor_id'] ))->row()->name; 
echo 'Drº '.$name;?> </b></div> 
<br> 
<br> 
<br> 

<?php foreach ($patient_info as $row2){ ?> 
<?php echo 'Nome do Paciente: '.$row2['name']; ?><br> 

<br> 
<br> 
<b><?php echo get_phrase('medication'); ?> :</b> 

<p><?php echo $row['medication']; ?></p> 
<br> 
<br> 
<?php } ?> 

<?php echo 'Data: '.date("d M, Y", $row['timestamp']); ?> 
<br> 

</b> 

</div> 

</div> 


<br> 

<a onClick="PrintElem('#prescription_print')" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon icon-left hidden-print"> 
Imprimir Prescrição 
<i class="entypo-doc-text"></i> 
</a> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Somos uma comunidade de linguá Portuguesa (Europeia e Brasileira), não existe necessidade do uso do inglês (e nem é recomendado), pois todos aqui em sua maioria falam apenas português. -- Mudei o titulo pois o problema parece ser em obter os dados e não na impressão.

Comment: Laravel ou Codeigniter?

Comment: Correção! Está em Codeigniter, tem toda razão! Peço desculpas pelos equívocos e agradeço pelo o seu auxílio. Namastê!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Eu não tenho certeza de qual o formato do seu banco e nem que versão do Laravel usa (parece que se trata de *CodeIgniter* como citado pelo [@gmsantos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82104/pegar-dados-do-banco-com-laravel#comment166600_82104)).</s>

Sendo CodeIgniter acredito que a solução seja algo como:

```
<div>
<?php
    $data = $this->db->get_where('doctor' , array('doctor_id' => $row['doctor_id'] ))->row();
?>
   <b><?php echo 'Drº ', $data->name;?></b><br>
   <b><?php echo 'Endereço ', $data->address;?></b><br>
   <b><?php echo 'Email ', $data->email;?></b><br>
   <b><?php echo 'Telefone ', $data->phone;?></b><br>
   <b><?php echo 'Profile ', $data->profile;?></b>
</div>
```

Note que tentei organizar teu código e adicionei o telefone é só um exemplo, (o uso do `<br>` é só pra quebrar a linha, você pode remover).

O código ficou assim, isto pega a linha com todos dados e seta na variável `$data` o objeto:

```
 $data = $this->db->get_where('doctor' , array('doctor_id' => $row['doctor_id'] ))->row();
```

- Pegar o nome `$data->name`
- Pegar o e-mail `$data->email`
- Pegar o telefone `$data->phone`
- Pegar o profile `$data->profile`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Incrível! Sou grato pela a sua orientação. Namastê!